# Dataprep "create dataset with parameters" does not take all files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataprep

I am struggling with having files in the way that Dataprep intends to have, when importing a parameterized dataset from Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

To be specific:

I store .csv files on GCS in a location:

```
/20190807/file1.csv
/20190807/file2.csv
/20190807/file3.csv
/20190808/file1.csv
/20190808/file2.csv
/20190808/file3.csv
/20190809/file1.csv
/20190809/file2.csv
/20190809/file3.csv
...
```

Then I create a Dataset with Parameters on this location using a *wildcard.

[image]

In addition:

- **Encoding**: I apply detect automatic structure, and I select `UTF-8` (as I store all my files with this encoding).
- **Columns**: I also make sure that all files have the same columns.

**Problem**:
However, for some reason or another, depending how the file has been saved I guess, Dataprep does not take all the files when importing them. When I take those two files, I cannot identify what is different about them. Both have been saved as a type `application/octet-stream` and I apply a `UTF-8` encoding.

As a consequence, when I export my output after the dataset is wrangled in a flow, **I miss some dates** (eg 20190808).

Is there therefore a tool that I can compare these two files, to see what is different about them, in order to prevent these things of happening. It is not an option to store them in different locations as I do not know in advance which files will be different.

I am really surprised about this shortcoming, and it would be great to have somehow a way to only check the columns for each files instead of also checking other "hidden" differences.

Comment: Are the files missing in the grid view or after running a job?

The transformer (grid view) will only the show the first file found unless you collect a sample.

Comment: They are missing in both (also after running the job)

Comment: There might be a problem indeed. If you believe this is a bug you should contact support. Note that you import all the files in a specific folder by clicking the + circle button in the file browser. Maybe this will fix your problem?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Import-Data-Page_57344837

Comment: A strange but possible scenario is that your files are being replaced by the ones with the same name. I couldn't find any kind of this restriction names for Dataprep. But can you try not to repeat the name on the different directories?

Comment: I have tried a simple example where I put two affected files in just one folder with different names and then try to import this directory. While the files have exactly the same column names, and also same encoding (UTF-8), it does not grab both files but just one of the files. I can imagine that there is something different behind the scenes (maybe I think both are encoded in the same way but it is not the case). In any case, when I open the files they really look the same to me (and both are also .csv, so honestly I don't understand what Dataprep is expecting).

Comment: Does it also happen when you use the import folder feature? Is the file listed in the datasources list tab of the job page results?

Comment: When I import only the folder that has not been taken, then it works. But in combination with other folders then it skips this folder. Eg it works for folders 1....5 and not for 6, but 6 independent works fine. Thats why I suspected that there must be some difference in the files in folder 6 vs 1...5, which I cannot decompose as the 1) extension is the same, 2) the columns are the same and 3) on google storage it looks like the same (all application/octat).

Comment: @JohnAndrews Are you still facing this issue?
If so please, try to reach out to support or in the google cloud dataprep slack channel: https://cloud.google.com/community/ as it hard to help you without asking for more details

Comment: @Hugues Yes still facing this issue. How do you register for that slack channel?